# Why this is the best move?

Tags: tactics, positional-play, beginner, queen-sacrifice

I'm new here, so I just like chess and I don’t study too deeply. I could not understand the move Qxe5. Can someone explain to me?

[image: I can't see]

Answer (score 10):

The move exploits three things:
1. The black knight on `f4` is trapped and will fall.
2. The black pawn on `d6` is pinned.
3. The black King is trapped behind its own pawns allowing the threat of a back-rank mate.

1. Qxe5 dxe5 2. Rxd8+ Qf8 3. Rxf8+ Kxf8 and White has stolen a pawn
2. Qxe5 Qxb3 2. Rxd6 and White has a lovely game

Comment: Or 1. Qxe5 Qxd2 2. Rxd2, or 1. Qxe5 g5 2. Rxd6. Right?

Answer (score -2):

This is the best move because if the pawn on D6 were to take the Queen, the following move would be to checkmate with the D2 rook.

Comment: It isn't checkmate, though - see [Tony Ennis' answer](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/9927/why-this-is-the-best-move/9932#9932).